# Javascript error: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automated-tests, browser-automation

I fail to find the cause for this error. It seems to be on the 4th line. I have tried various different ways. Could anyone point out where I am going wrong with this pls?

```
public WebElement jsQuery(String componentQuery) {
    String cmd = "arguments[0].querySelector('" + componentQuery +"')";
    String js = "return " + cmd + ".id;";
   // String id = (String) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('" + componentQuery +"').id");
    String id = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js);
    waitForJavascript(5000, 3);
    return driver.findElement(By.id(id));
}
```

Comment: What is this function called with?

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: Never mind, I see that it's executing JS internally.

Comment: What is the value of `componentQuery`

Comment: Try writing out the JavaScript on its own first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape quotes in the `componentQuery` Java variable.

```java
String componentQueryEscaped = componentQuery.replaceAll("'", "\'");
```

you can also change your JS code to use the backtick instead of single quote:

```js
"arguments[0].querySelector(`" + componentQuery + "`)";
```

But the first solution is more solid.